# Hibernate TransientObjectException on OneToMany with CascadeType.ALL if we call iterator() before save

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-cascade

I have OneToMany Relation in hibernate like below:

```
class Container {
    @OneToMany( cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "container", orphanRemoval = true)
    List<Item> items;
}
```

the simplified scenario is that I load a `Container` object (container) from the database and try to add an `Item` to `container.items` like this:

```
Container container = entityManager.find(Container.class,id);
container.getItems().add(new Item(container));
entityManager.merge(container);
```

and everything goes fine. But in my case, I want to iterate over items and check something, but when I just call `container.getItems().iterator` and save `container` like this:

```
Container container = entityManager.find(Container.class,id);
container.getItems().add(new Item(container));
container.getItems().iterator(); // here is the change
entityManager.merge(container); // here is where exception occured
```

I get the following error

> org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance beforeQuery flushing: mypackage.items

I have no idea why this exception occurs.

Comment: Can you try using listIterator instead of iterator?

Comment: @GarimaGupta No, same error.

Comment: What happens if you `persist()` the new item before adding to the list?

Comment: @yegodm it works but what was wrong about `iterator()`, I want to use it to remove duplicates from the items.

Comment: What is your version of Hibernate? I cannot reproduce the case with 5.2.12.

Comment: Its `5.2.4.Final`

Comment: Can't reproduce with 5.2,4 either. What's your `Item` mapping?

Comment: what do you mean by "`Item` mapping"?
    ```@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    Container container;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    Tag tag;```

Comment: Dunno, whatever I try works fine. What is the database you are using?

Comment: Postgres v9.6.6

Answer (score 2):

Your item object needs to have a reference to its parent:

```
Container container = entityManager.find(Container.class,id);
Item item = new Item();
item.setContainer(container); //needed
container.getItems().add(item);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I did that. But since I simplified my code, I removed it. the interesting thing is that the problem occurs only when I call `iterator()`. Otherwise, everything is fine.

Comment: This exception occurs when trying to use the Domain property with the data model having detached state. You need to explicitly fetch the Domain Object using the property and use this fetched object further using session.load(yourTransientObject)